# Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when dealing with prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to get the camera follow my player (which is instantiated from a prefab) but I keep getting the error in my camera script.

My camera script (the error is in line  `offset = transform.position - Game.currentPlayer.transform.position;`):

```cs
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 offset;

    private void Awake()
    {
        offset = transform.position - Game.currentPlayer.transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Game.currentPlayer.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

I set my `currentPlayer` variable here:

```cs
void Start()
    {
        GameObject newPlayer = Instantiate(player,transform.position,transform.rotation);
        newPlayer.name = "Player";
        currentPlayer = newPlayer;
    }
```

If you need anymore scripts to help, just ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) is called before [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html). Actually even **all** `Awake` methods are finished **before** the first `Start` is called (also see [`Order of Execution for Event Functions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)).

Therefore the reference is not set yet in `Awake`.

You will have to either move it to the `Start` method or move the instantiation part to `Awake`.

In both cases it is still no warranty that the `Game` script will have its `Start` executed before the `GameControl`. Therefore you will still have to adjust the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) thus that `Game` is always excuted before `GameControl`. Simply

- open the Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order
- drag&drop in the `Game` script before the `DefaultTime` block
- optionally also sortr already existing items

---

Alternatively you could use an event system:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action OnInitilalized;

    public static GameObject currentPlayer;

    privtae void Start()
    {
        GameObject newPlayer = Instantiate(player,transform.position,transform.rotation);
        newPlayer.name = "Player";
        currentPlayer = newPlayer;

        OnInitilalized?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and then in the `GameControl` add a callback to the `OnInitialized` event like

```
private void Awake()
{
    // This makes sure the callback is added only once
    Game.OnInitialized -= OnGameInitialized;
    Game.OnInitialized += OnGameInitialized;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    // always make sure to remove callbacks if no longer needed
    Game.OnInitialized -= OnGameInitialized;
}

privtae void OnGameInitialized()
{
    offset = transform.position - Game.currentPlayer.transform.position;
}
```